# Loading shared Javascript code between vue-electron components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, es6-modules

I've created a new vue-electron project using `vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue <my project name>`. I can create some basic components that use a database backend like so (`src/rendered/components/Tagger/TagList.vue`):

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="tag in tags">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="tag" :value="tag" v-model="selectedTags">
      <label :for="tag">{{ tag }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {

    var db, sqlite3, tags;
    sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
    db = new sqlite3.Database('/tmp/tagister.tmp.sqlite3');
    tags = [];
    db.each("SELECT id,tag FROM tags", function(err, row) {
      tags.push(row.tag)
    });
    db.close;

    return {
      tags: tags,
      selectedTags: ['someTag']
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I have a Tagger.vue that imports that component and it renders correctly, pulling a list of tags from the sqlite database.

Now I want to abstract the database code so I can use it with multiple components. I created a `database.js`. It looks like this:

```
"use strict";

sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')

export default class Database {
  constructor(dbFile) {
    this.db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);
    log.console('Opened Database: ' + dbFile)
  }

  tags() {
    var tags = [];
    this.db.each("SELECT id,tag FROM tags", function(err, row) {
      tags.push(row.tag)
    });
    return tags;
  }

  files() {
    var files = [];
    this.db.each("SELECT id,name FROM files", function(err, row) {
      files.push(row.name)
    });
    return files;
  }

  close() {
    this.db.close();
  }
}
```

I've tried placing it in `src` and `src/main` and tried importing it using `var db = requrie('database')` and `var db = require('src/main/database')` and several other variations, but I always get an error that the module cannot be found. What's the correct way to build and import modules in vue-electron projects?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up settling placing my database library in the `src/render` part of the tree. My `src/renderer/database.coffee` looked like the following:

```
Database = require('better-sqlite3')

class TagDB

  constructor: (dbFile) ->
    @db = new Database(dbFile)
    console.log("Opened Database #{dbFile}")

  tags: ->
    @db.prepare("SELECT id,tag FROM tags").all().map( (row) => row.tag )

  files: ->
    @db.prepare("SELECT id,name FROM files").all()

  close: ->
    @db.close()

export default TagDB
```

Then I have a component at `src/renderer/components/Tagger.vue` which has the following in its `<script>` section:

```
<script>
  import TagDB from '../database'
  var tagdb = new TagDB('/tmp/tagster.tmp.sqlite3')
  ...
  ...
```

And finally I added the following to `.electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js` so I could compile my coffeescript:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:  /\.coffee$/,
        use: 'coffeescript-loader'
      },
  ...
  ...
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.css', '.node', '.coffee']
```